# As a Buddhist lay-follower is there a need and good form to do good deeds?

Tags: karma, compassion

As I've started to consider myself a lay-Buddhist for at least five years now, I've had an inclination to do good. But I've found it difficult to give it proper form.

I've found that politics are not the way for me, to much based on ego's and manipulation. But even doing just volunteer work or a food bank or help for refugees I've felt part of political machinations and power games.

Maybe this question is to much about opinion, but I was wondering:

- Is there a need to good deeds as a lay-Buddhist?
- What is are proper way of doing so, avoiding just giving money, or becoming to political?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, good deeds are very useful to us! Read the [Cula Kamma Vibhanga Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.nymo.html) and the [Maha Kamma Vibhanga sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.136.nymo.html) to get an idea of how good and bad Karma can affect our lives drastically.

You can do good deeds on your own without depending on political mechanisms. But if you have to get involved, focus on the good aspect to it, instead of the political side.

Answer (score 0):

buddha mentioned 3 ways of doing good deeds. thru  1) action, 2) speech, 3) mind

action:  Sila (precepts, charity , etch) 
Speech:  kinda words,
Mind: meditation, removing defilement, kindness projection..  etc